# pdo update statement using variable as table name

Tags: php, mysql

the pdo update statement below doesn't work due the table name ties to a variable. Does anyone know how to make it work?

```
    $stmt1 = $DB_CON_C->prepare('UPDATE `".$account_list."`
    SET property_type=:property_type; property_address=:property_address, property_city=:property_city, property_state=:property_state, property_zip=:property_zip WHERE contract_number=:order_list');
    $stmt1->bindParam(':account_list', $account_list, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt1->bindParam(':order_list', $order_list, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt1->bindParam(':property_class', $property_class, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt1->bindParam(':property_type', $property_type, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt1->bindParam(':property_address', $property_address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt1->bindParam(':property_city', $property_city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt1->bindParam(':property_state', $property_state, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt1->bindParam(':property_zip', $property_zip, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt1->execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to user single quotes in stead of double:

```
$stmt1 = $DB_CON_C->prepare('UPDATE `' .$account_list. '`
    SET property_type=:property_type; property_address=:property_address, property_city=:property_city, property_state=:property_state, property_zip=:property_zip WHERE contract_number=:order_list');
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, just simplify, and do:

```
->prepare("UPDATE {$account_list} SET...
```

Ie, use double quotes. The `{}` isn't needed, but I prefer using them because I personally use this as a prefix to the actual table name (so `("SELECT * FROM {$dbprefix}tablename")`)

This way you do not need to concoct strings inside the query, which you shouldn't need to do. Just wrap the query in double quotes instead.

Comment: Thanks. This way seems to be better and simpler.